# I'm currently using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and I want to know whether it is possible to delay the ESB service response

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm currently using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and I want to know whether it is possible to delay the ESB response from within the service.
That is, if a response arrives from the relevant backend, output it from the ESB service with a delay of a certain time.(example 60000ms)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a thread sleep [1].

```
<script language="js">java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000);</script>
```

[1]-http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-add-sleep-interval-or-delay.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this approach but now when I increase the sleep value beyond 45000ms, a java socket timeout occurs. I set the http.socket.timeout=300000 in passthru-http.properties but still no luck. Any approach to prevent the java socket timeout?

Comment: can you refer to the stackoverflow question in [1].
[1]-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694671/wso2-esb-connection-timeout-tuning